Householder transformation and construction of the new one
The householder transformation is a transformation of the form $V_{k}=I-\frac{2vv*}{v*v}$. for some $v$, where $v*$ is conjugate transpose of $v$. I need to prove that if ${V_{k}}$ is a Householder transformation then $H_{k}=$\begin{pmatrix}
  I_{k-1} & 0\\ 
  0 & {V_{k}}\\
\end{pmatrix} is also a Householder transformation.
My attempt:
I must express \begin{pmatrix}
  I_{k-1} & 0\\ 
  0 & {V_{k}}\\
\end{pmatrix} in the form of $I-\frac{2vv*}{v*v}$ for some $v$ but I do not know how to do that technically. It is not obvious.
Thank you in advance.

Consider vector $w = \begin{pmatrix}0_{k-1}\\v\end{pmatrix}$ (i.e. $v$ with $k-1$ leading zeros):
$$
w^*w = v^*v
$$
and
$$
ww^* = \begin{pmatrix}0_{k-1}\\v\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0^T_{k-1} & v^*\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & vv^*\end{pmatrix}.
$$
So we have:
$$
I_{2k-1} - \frac{2ww^*}{w^*w} = I_{2k-1} - \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{2vv^*}{v^*v}\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}I_{k-1} & 0 \\ 0 & I_k - \frac{2vv^*}{v^*v}\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}I_{k-1} & 0 \\ 0 & V_k\end{pmatrix} = H_k.
$$

Hello, thank you what is the dimension of $(0_{k-1})$ and $v$?

@mathsandchess $0_{k-1} \in \mathbb{R}^{k-1}$ and $v \in \mathbb{C}^{k}$

Thank you for your help okay now
